# VBA How to create Cell Bottom Border every 5 rows for only Visible Cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am looking to apply a bottom border to every 5th visible row.

The loop starts with row 14 and continues through row 200.

I would like for the loop to look for a value in cells(i, "D"). ie every *ith* row in column D.

Currently I am getting an Object Required error on the row where I set x = 0. I am confused about this since I declared x as an Integer at the top.

```
Sub Border()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim sumsht As Worksheet
Set sumsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

x = 0

  For i = 14 To 200
    x = sumsht.Cells(i, "D") + x
        If x = 5 Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        Else
        End If  
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: x is not an object, it's a variable. Remove the "Set" ... `x=0`

Comment: `Set` is a keyword reserved for object variable assignments.  Object variables are things like a Workbook, Worksheet, Range, or Control (Textbox, Combobox, etc).  An Integer is not considered an object by VBA, so the `Set` keyword is causing an error because it's expect an Object variable when instead its an Integer variable.  Simply remove the `Set` from that line.

Comment: You haven't set sumsht to anything. It is an object.

Comment: Changes have been made now I'm getting a new error: Type Mismatch with x = sumsht.Cells(i, "D") + x

Answer (score 4):

Try this. You need to account for the height of the row.

Also as others said, set is used with ranges not just variables (like your x). You also use `sumsht` but do not define it anywhere.

```
Option Explicit
Sub add_lines()
Dim rw, ct As Integer


ct = 0

For rw = 14 To 200
    If Rows(rw).Height <> 0 Then
        ct = ct + 1
    End If
    If ct = 5 Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(rw).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        ct = 0
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

to remove other borders use this (thanks @Comintern):

```
Range("A1:D22").Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to remove the previous row borders before the loop?

Comment: @Max You mean remove all of the existing borders? Or what?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Though it would be great if I could isolate the range that we are removing the borders from.

Comment: @Max Since I don't know the range you mean, I added code that will remove all borders. To generate it I just recorded a macro of setting border to none for a range.

Comment: @Max, if this solution meets your needs, be sure to mark it as accepted so that others who have similar issues will know there is a solution

Comment: A much easier way to clear all the borders is `Range("A1:D22").Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone`.

Comment: @Max if this answers your question please mark it as the answer so others can find it! Thanks